# Nested function structure make setInterval function unvisible

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

code1

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTime(){
            var c=document.getElementById("text");
            var nowTime=new Date();
            c.innerHTML="time is  "+nowTime.toLocaleTimeString();
            }
    function startTime(){
        setInterval("showTime()",1000);
        }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It operates successfully,now to nest showTime function in the startTime function.

code2

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startTime(){
        function showTime(){
            var c=document.getElementById("text");
            var nowTime=new Date();
            c.innerHTML="time is  "+nowTime.toLocaleTimeString();
        }
        setInterval("showTime()",1000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

An error occur ,`ReferenceError: showTime is not defined`.
1.For code1, what is the uasge of double quotes in setInterval function?
2.For code2, Why showTime can be called from startTime such as in code1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be the eval scope issue.

```js
function test() {
  var x = 2,
    y = 4;
  console.log(eval("x + y")); // Direct call, uses local scope, result is 6
  var geval = eval;
  console.log(geval("x + y")); // Indirect call, uses global scope, throws ReferenceError because `x` is undefined
}
test();
```

Internally setInterval Also Uses eval to determine the function.
As a result due to this behavior of direct and indirect calling it will throw a reference error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 0):

`"showTime()"` is a string not a callable.
The right way is:

```
 function startTime(){
        function showTime(){
            var c=document.getElementById("text");
            var nowTime=new Date();
            c.innerHTML="time is  "+nowTime.toLocaleTimeString();
        }
        setInterval(showTime,1000);
    }
```

Comment: string version actually is callable and valid in setTimeout or setInterval...uses `eval()` internally...scoping won't work though

Comment: Eval() Is Used Internally To Handle This
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Ok, but when `eval()` is used the javascript will look for the `showTime` in global space where it is not present. I've tryed my solution and it works.